# JasperReports NullPointer only when running from complied jar

Tags: java, jar, jasper-reports, inputstream

I am getting a weird null pointer, If I run the project from netbeans, the programs works just fine, but when I run the compiled jar I get a weird NullPointer whe I'm trying to load the `JasperReport`

I have this class that generates the report, by obtaining an `InputStream` from within the jar, generates the parameters `Map`, and selects the appropiate `Connection`:

```
class ImpresorRemesas {

void mostrarRemesa(String remesa) {
    String titulo = String.format("Remesa %s", remesa);
    InputStream reporte = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/ttracasa/remesas/remesa.jasper");
    Map parametros = new HashMap();
    parametros.put("remesa", remesa);
    Image logo = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/com/ttracasa/remesas/imag_tracasa.jpg")).getImage();
    parametros.put("logo", logo);
    ReporteJasper.mostrar(titulo, reporte, parametros, Remesas.connection);
}
}
```

Notice that I also parametrize resources from within the jar to the `Map`, I don't think is relevant but nevertheless.

This `InputStream`, `Map` and `Connection` are passed along to a static utility class, which loads the `JasperReport` , fills the `JasperPrint` and displays the `JasperViewer`

```
public static void mostrar(String titulo, InputStream stream, Map<String,Object> parametros, Connection connection) {
    try {
        JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(stream);
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parametros, connection);
        JasperViewer jasperViewer = new JasperViewer(jasperPrint, false);
        jasperViewer.setTitle(titulo);
        jasperViewer.setVisible(true);
    } catch (JRException ex) {
        UtileriaGui.mensajeError(ex, null);
    }
}
```

If I run the project from Netbeans, it works as expected, however, after I compile the jar, I get this `NullPointerException`.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(UnknownSource)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.ContextClassLoaderObjectInputStream.<init>(ContextClassLoaderObjectInputStream.java:56)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:277)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:262)
at com.ttracasa.utilerias.ReporteJasper.mostrar(ReporteJasper.java:36)
...
```

I thought it might have something to do with the jar, but I checked and the resources are inside at the expected path. I also thought it might have to do with my path use of slashes (i.e. `/com/ttracasa/etcetera` instead of `/com\\ttracasa\\etcetera`) but does not seems to be the case, it might have something to do with the `InputStream` being mishandled before `JRLoader` works with it, but why? what am I missing? it works like a charm within the IDE.

The class `ImpresorRemesas` and my utils are in different jar files, but I dont think it should make any difference.

According to [getResourceAsStream() documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) this method returns null if no resource with this name is found. I checked and this seems to be the case, when running from inside the jar the resource can't be found because if I check the stream it is in fact `NULL`

Perhaps it has something to do with how the manifest is being generated:

> 

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.10.4
Created-By: 1.8.0_201-b09 (Oracle Corporation)
Class-Path: lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar lib/jcalendar-1.4.
 jar lib/jasperreports-6.9.0.jar lib/commons-beanutils-1.9.3.jar lib/c
 ommons-collections4-4.2.jar lib/commons-digester-2.1.jar lib/commons-
 logging-1.1.1.jar lib/groovy-all-2.4.16.jar lib/itext-2.1.7.js6.jar l
 ib/poi-4.0.1.jar lib/jfreechart-1.0.19.jar lib/UtileriaGeneral.jar li
 b/Permisos.jar lib/Oficinas.jar
Main-Class: com.ttracasa.remesas.Remesas
```

Comment: " I checked and the resources are inside at the expected path" - in the same jar file as `ImpresorRemesas.class`? Can you show us the content of the jar file?

Comment: 9/10 times when you run into NPE issues with `getResourceAsStream` it's a packaging error. It might be helpful to see how you're building your JAR file (i.e. Ant, Maven or Gradle config)

Comment: I see `ImpresorRemesas.class` at the same folder as `remesa.jasper` and `img_tracasa.jpg` in `/com/ttracasa/remesas/`  and is being packaged with good old `Ant`

Comment: Ah, then your path is the issue. It should be `getClass().getResourceAsStream("remesa.jasper");`

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke same issue, by using the relative path works on Netbeans but throws NPE from jar... https://imgur.com/a/OPShAdy jar contents

Comment: In your JAR the file has an uppercase `R` in the name. Have you tried using the **exact** name of the file (`Remesa.jasper`)? Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/234999/2738151).

Comment: omg!!! it is a case sensitivity problem!!... such a noob, why didn't I tried it, thanks @HernánAlarcón guess I'm just getting so used to freaking windows that I forgot all about case